# imageName is null when add image using Vich Uploader with validator

Tags: symfony, doctrine, vichuploaderbundle, symfony-validator

when i upload an image using vich uploader with validation, it will return "imageName should not be null" error message. I can't figure out the reason what it cause that.

---

Vich uploader config:

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm

    mappings:
        home_partner_alliance:
            uri_prefix: /image/home/partnerAlliance
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/image/home/partnerAlliance'
```

My controller:

```
/* 
  --- router annotation ---
*/
public function addImage(Request $request, ValidatorInterface $validator)
{
    $file = $request->files->get('image');
    $home = new HomePartnerAlliance();
    $home->setImageFile($file);
    $home->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());

    $errors = $validator->validate($home);
    if(count($errors) == 0){
        $this->em->persist($home);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
    else
    {
        $messages = [];
        foreach($errors as $error)
        {
            $messages[$error->getPropertyPath()] = $error->getMessage();
        }
    }

    return new JsonResponse(['status'=> $messages]);
}
```

My entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\HomePartnerAllianceRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class HomePartnerAlliance
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="home_partner_alliance", fileNameProperty="imageName")
 * @Assert\File(mimeTypes = {"image/jpeg", "image/png"})
 */
private $imageFile;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $imageName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 */
private $updatedAt;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function setImageFile(?File $imageFile = null): void
{
    $this->imageFile = $imageFile;

    if (null !== $imageFile) {
        // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
        // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
    }
}

public function getImageFile(): ?File
{
    return $this->imageFile;
}

public function getImageName(): ?string
{
    return $this->imageName;
}

public function setImageName(?string $imageName): self
{
    $this->imageName = $imageName;

    return $this;
}

public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
{
    return $this->updatedAt;
}

public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $updatedAt): self
{
    $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

    return $this;
}
}
```

---

So when i post a image to my controller, it will return me a error message:

```
{
  "status": {
    "imageName": "This value should not be null."
  }
}
```

I try upload an invalid type of file, it will return me imageName Null as well:

```
{
  "status": {
    "imageFile": "The mime type of the file is invalid (\"image\/vnd.adobe.photoshop\"). Allowed mime types are \"image\/jpeg\", \"image\/png\".",
    "imageName": "This value should not be null."
  }
}
```

But when i remove the validation code in my controller, it is successfully add the image to the folder and image name is saved to database. Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the `namer` property in your Vich mapping.

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm

    mappings:
        home_partner_alliance:
            uri_prefix: /image/home/partnerAlliance
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/image/home/partnerAlliance'
            namer: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\UniqidNamer
```

Comment: I figured out that i need to set image name manually like $home->setImageName($file->getClientOriginalName()) otherwise my imageName is always null during validation check. But some of my entity show no error during validation check. I am so curious about it.